# Cloning/Ghosting computers that have LogMeIn installed

Tags: clone, logmein, ghost

Good afternoon,

We prepare ghost images for each of the computers we manage. Basically we start with a running system (previous image), perform a number of manual changes to the system's configuration (install/configure software, change network settings, etc.), and generate a DVD image for this computer. The DVD is then loaded up in the target computer (in another country) and is then ready to go.

We want LMI installed on these computers. However, when we uninstall LMI and re-install it (to give this new computer a different name from the previous one), the original computer is removed from LMI Central. I assume removing computers when uninstalling the software is desired behaviour in most cases, but it is problematic for us.

How can we tell LMI that this is a new computer without affecting the previous one?

I thought about disconnecting the network cable when uninstalling LMI, but am not sure this would work as intended. What is the best workaround?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you not have LMI installed when you make the image, install it on each deployed pc after the fact?

Comment: @Moab - while this is the normal solution for this kind of thing, it kind of falls down when you have to ship the image a long distance. He needs something more creative.

Comment: What does distance have to do with my solution, just install LMI on the other end, unless they have no one competent to do that. Some of the best solutions are simple, not creative.

Comment: @Moab - it's not the distance, it's the personnel

Comment: For me, that doesn't work as the computer is completely locked down and the end user cannot be involved in the installation process.

Answer (score 2):

I think you might need to move to a two-stage install.  Ship one DVD with the image and one CD with a script you run after installing the image.  The script can do things like install Log Me In.  You can also use this to simplify your images - with some work, you ought to be able to get down to one images for *all* of your PCs rather than one image for *each* PC.

Comment: Although this is an option, the amount of work to make it work and be fully automated is too much for the low volume of cloning we need to do. (Not only for LogMeIn but for the other things we install on the machine, which include various types of legacy hardware peripherals, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to detail the same problem different perspective and a manual solution w/ LogMeIn on Mac OS X Snow Leopard.

I duplicate a hard drive for use in a different computer (or use migration assistant).
The new (duplicated) machine gets a new computer name (hostname) which resolves syncing problems in all programs - the exception being LMI. I've fumbled plenty in the LMI site and configurations, renaming the machines/profiles etc., but continually get the same **problem - two machines fighting for the same LMI slot: knocking each other "ready but offline"**. Re-installing the software doesn't help here.

My manual solution is to delete the computer from the LMI site, wait for grey LMI tray icons - click 'Open Logmein...' - click button "Choose account and subscription" - this lets me supply credentials and a new computer name.   Unfortunately the new name is ignored! the second machine I do this to gets named "old name(1)" and I must name the machines at the LMI website.  At least there isn't a (re)install process, but I would also like something more graceful / automated.

I would love to find which file LMI is using to key the machines uniquely (thumbprint) to remove or modify it during my duplication process.

-Z

Comment: I got some answers from LMI - simply that our types of scenarios aren't directly supported. If you find something that works on the Mac, please let me know.